# What is the latest Spark-Redis connector version we can install in databricks cluster?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-redis-cache, spark-redis

What is the latest spark-redis version we can install in databricks cluster ?

I will be using **python/pyspark** to write the dataframe to redis.

My Databricks runtime :10.2 (includes Apache Spark 3.2.0, Scala 2.12)

In Databricks, we can see only **spark-redis 2.3.0 version** in maven (install library-->maven-->search packages-->redis.

[image: Databricks-Cluster-Library]

Below is a screenshot from spark-redis github documentation.

[image: spark-redis version in github documentation]

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/68218806/2986344

Comment: @Sai Did you figure which spark-redis library's version to use with spark 3.2